# ORACLE - unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 95

Tags: oracle, spring-boot

Below is my Oracle SQL Query to find last 12 months of count according to the status(column - 'OVRL_MET_ST' in DB) as pass or fail , where CSL_ENHANCE_CHANGES is a table in ORACLE DB with columns SRL_NO_TXT as id(primary key), MNTH_TXT of date datatype(Ex."01-APR-17"), OVRL_MET_ST(varchar datatype) consists of  status(i.e. 'pass' or 'fail')

```
select months.month , 
       cec.ovrlMetSt as Status , 
       coalesce(count(cec.srlNoTxt), 0) as Count 
from (select to_char( trunc(sysdate) - numtoyminterval(level - 1, 'month'), 'mon-yy') as month 
      from dual connect by level <= 12) months 
LEFT outer join CSL_ENHANCE_CHANGES cec 
    on to_char(months.month) = to_char( trunc(mnthTxt), 'mon-yy') 
group by months.month,cec.ovrlMetSt;
```

This is result on executing the Oracle query

```
Month   Status  Count
feb-17  Pass        1
dec-16  null        0
oct-17  null        0
may-17  Pass        1
jul-17  null        0
sep-17  null        0
aug-17  null        0
apr-17  Pass        2
jun-17  null        0
jan-17  Pass        1
nov-17  null        0
mar-17  Pass        1
apr-17  Fail        1
```

I am using hql query in my code as shown below

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

List<Object[]> namedlist= (List<Object[]>) em.createQuery(
                        "select months.month, cec.ovrlMetSt as Status , coalesce(count(cec.srlNoTxt), 0) as Count from (select to_char( trunc(sysdate) - numtoyminterval(level - 1, 'month'), 'mon-yy') as month from dual connect by level <= 12) months LEFT outer join CSL_ENHANCE_CHANGES cec on to_char(months.month) = to_char( trunc(mnthTxt), 'mon-yy') group by months.month,cec.ovrlMetSt"
                        ).getResultList();
```

On Googling I found that, HQL does not support sub-queries within from clause. So, would changing the query be a viable option, if yes what will the query be? if no, is there any other way that Spring-Boot Framework can handle

Comment: You can also create a native query

Comment: I am quite new to this, could you please tell me how and what will be changed in the query?

Comment: take a look to this [jpa-native-queries](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-native-queries/)

Comment: Yes, you can try MyBatis!!! Its not an ORM like Hibernate, but its amazing because you can write SQL in your XML files. Much more flexible.

Comment: @Patrick I tried with native query it's still giving the same error

Comment: can you show your changes

Comment: @Patrick  changed the createQuery(....) to createNativeQuery(.....)

Comment: @Everyone We can change the sub-query within from clause to where clause, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        buffer.append(" select  cec.OVRL_MET_ST as Status ,to_date(months.month, 'mon-yy') as MONTH_TXT ,  ");
        buffer.append(" coalesce(count(cec.SRL_NO_TXT), 0) as Count from  ");
        buffer.append(
                " (select to_char( trunc(sysdate-3) - numtoyminterval(level - 1, 'month'), 'mon-yy') as month from dual connect by level <= 12) months ");
        buffer.append(" LEFT outer join CSL_ENHANCE_CHANGES cec on ");
        buffer.append("  to_char(months.month) = to_char( trunc(MNTH_TXT), 'mon-yy') ");
        buffer.append("  group by months.month,cec.OVRL_MET_ST ");
        query = buffer.toString();

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet reset = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```